# Get Downstream Job Details in the Upstream Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to get the downstream job details so that I can update this in my Upstream Job short desc or some log file.

But I'm unable to find any call that will work. For getting the Upstream Job info, there is `getUpstreamCause(..)` but nothing similar for `DownstreamCause`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to this. 
Javadoc reference : https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html

```
def job = build job: 'DownstreamJob'
println job.getId()
```

The javadoc has all the details I require.

Answer (score 0):

```
def startedJobld = build(
    job: YOUR_DOWNSTREAM_JOB,
    wait: true, //  **IMPORTANT, otherwise build () does not return expected object**
    propagate: true

println startedJobld .getId()

)
```